# Make TikZ overlay part of a formula bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, bounding-box

I have a formula, annotated using a TikZ picture overlay:

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.
\[ \tikzmarknode{A}{3} + \frac{\tikzmarknode{Bn}{\makebox[\widthof{7}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
    \tikzmarknode{Bd}{7} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{Cn}{\makebox[\widthof{15}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
        \tikzmarknode{Cd}{15} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{Dn}{1}\hfill}{
            \tikzmarknode{Dd}{1} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{En}{\makebox[\widthof{292}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
                \tikzmarknode{Ed}{292} + \tikzmarknode{F}{\dfrac{1}{1}}}}}} \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(A)]        (Abox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Bn) (Bd)]  (Bbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Cn) (Cd)]  (Cbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Dn) (Dd)]  (Dbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(En) (Ed)]  (Ebox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(F)]        (Fbox){};
\draw (A.south)  node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $A$};
\draw (Bd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $B$};
\draw (Cd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $C$};
\draw (Dd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $D$};
\draw (Ed.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $E$};
\draw (F.south)  node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $F$};
\end{tikzpicture}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

As expected, the text ignores the overlay and the F fills the normal spacing after the formula. How to make LaTeX to consider the annotations as a part of the formula bounding box and thus adding the required space below the letter F?

If I make the `tikzpicture` not `overlay`, it doesn’t work as intended.

---

## First try (not working)

Following Qrrbrbirlbel’s advice, I created a tikzpicture that does everything including the formula. However, not only the annotation are in a different place than the formula, but the whole thing needs 3 pages.

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (0,0) {$\subnode{A}{3} + \dfrac{\subnode{Bn}{\makebox[\widthof{7}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
    \subnode{Bd}{7} + \dfrac{\subnode{Cn}{\makebox[\widthof{15}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
        \subnode{Cd}{15} + \dfrac{\subnode{Dn}{1}\hfill}{
            \subnode{Dd}{1} + \dfrac{\subnode{En}{\makebox[\widthof{292}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
                \subnode{Ed}{292} + \subnode{F}{\dfrac{1}{1}}}}}}$};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(A)]        (Abox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Bn) (Bd)]  (Bbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Cn) (Cd)]  (Cbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Dn) (Dd)]  (Dbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(En) (Ed)]  (Ebox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(F)]        (Fbox){};
\draw (A.south)  node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $A$};
\draw (Bd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $B$};
\draw (Cd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $C$};
\draw (Dd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $D$};
\draw (Ed.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $E$};
\draw (F.south)  node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $F$};
\end{tikzpicture}

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

---

## Second try (nearly working)

I found a solution that nearly work by tweaking the bounding box of the overlay picture. However, the space below is still too small:

```tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.
\[ \tikzmarknode{A}{3} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{Bn}{\makebox[\widthof{7}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
    \tikzmarknode{Bd}{7} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{Cn}{\makebox[\widthof{15}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
        \tikzmarknode{Cd}{15} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{Dn}{1}\hfill}{
            \tikzmarknode{Dd}{1} + \dfrac{\tikzmarknode{En}{\makebox[\widthof{292}][c]{1}}\hfill}{
                \tikzmarknode{Ed}{292} + \tikzmarknode{F}{\dfrac{1}{1}}}}}} \]%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\path[use as bounding box] (F.south west) rectangle (F.north east);
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(A)]        (Abox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Bn) (Bd)]  (Bbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Cn) (Cd)]  (Cbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(Dn) (Dd)]  (Dbox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(En) (Ed)]  (Ebox){};
\node[fill=gray!30,blend mode=darken,rectangle,inner sep=1pt,fit=(F)]        (Fbox){};
\draw (A.south)  node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $A$};
\draw (Bd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $B$};
\draw (Cd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $C$};
\draw (Dd.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $D$};
\draw (Ed.south) node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $E$};
\draw (F.south)  node[below=2pt] {\footnotesize $F$};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Comment: This might be a poor solution, but maybe add a `\vspace`? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Someone this is exactly what I want to avoid. I’ll do this if there is no other solution.

Comment: That's the disadvantages of all those tikzmark-overlay solutions. You can let TikZ measure the additional space (basically the height of a footnotesized `$F$` + 2× inner ysep + 2pt) and let it also add it as a `\vspace`. Alternatively, you typeset the whole formula as one node inside TikZ and replace the `\tikzmarknode`s with `\subnode`s. Then you don't need a separate TikZ picture with overlay.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel your solution is very interesting but I am unable to make it work. See the edited question. I found a nearly working solution by myself but it’s not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I use a phantom `\underset` to increase the height of the equation.  It is called through the command `\edenominator` on the final fraction instead of `\denominator`.

I tried to simplifythe code in the file  and make it uniform, but, on the whole, it is almost your initial code.

In the figure, the equation appears two times.  First with the additional vertical distance; second without it for comparison.

**The code**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc, fit, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\numerator}[3]{\tikzmarknode{#2n}{\makebox[\widthof{#3}][c]{#1}}\hfill}
\newcommand{\denominator}[2]{\tikzmarknode{#2d}{#1}}
\newcommand{\edenominator}[2]{\underset{\phantom{.}}{\tikzmarknode{#2d}{#1}}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non
risus.  Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, 
ultricies sed, dolor. 
\[
  \tikzmarknode{A}{3}
  + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{B}{7}}{\denominator{7}{B}
    + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{C}{15}}{\denominator{15}{C}
      + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{D}{1}}{\denominator{1}{D}
        + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{E}{292}}{\denominator{292}{E}
          + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{F}{1}}{\edenominator{1}{F}}}}}}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
  a/.style={fill=gray!30, blend mode=darken, rectangle, inner sep=1pt},
  a-label/.style={label={[scale=.8, label distance=2pt] 270:$#1$}}]
  \node[a, fit=(A), a-label={A}] (Abox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Bn) (Bd), a-label={B}] (Bbox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Cn) (Cd), a-label={C}] (Cbox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Dn) (Dd), a-label={D}] (Dbox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(En) (Ed), a-label={E}] (Ebox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Fn) (Fd), a-label={F}] (Fbox) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing
nec, ultricies sed, dolor. 


\vspace{30pt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing
nec, ultricies sed, dolor.
\[
  \tikzmarknode{A}{3}
  + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{B}{7}}{\denominator{7}{B}
    + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{C}{15}}{\denominator{15}{C}
      + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{D}{1}}{\denominator{1}{D}
        + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{E}{292}}{\denominator{292}{E}
          + \dfrac{\numerator{1}{F}{1}}{\denominator{1}{F}}}}}}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
  a/.style={fill=gray!30, blend mode=darken, rectangle, inner sep=1pt},
  a-label/.style={label={[scale=.8, label distance=2pt] 270:$#1$}}]
  \node[a, fit=(A), a-label={A}] (Abox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Bn) (Bd), a-label={B}] (Bbox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Cn) (Cd), a-label={C}] (Cbox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Dn) (Dd), a-label={D}] (Dbox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(En) (Ed), a-label={E}] (Ebox) {};
  \node[a, fit=(Fn) (Fd), a-label={F}] (Fbox) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing
nec, ultricies sed, dolor.
 
\end{document}
```